# Background image does not seem to fill entire screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, fullscreen

The below picture shows that there are vertical "lines" running down the sides of each side of the screen.  The background image seems to fill most of the screen but then there are these lines and the picture does not line up.  See where I marked these lines with the black arrows.  There seems to be no horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the screen.  I cannot find any reason for this.

[image]

Below is some relevant code that might be where the problem is residing.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MainMenu"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Here is a section of my `styles.xml` that is referenced in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, this problem occurs on all the layouts, not just the one below.

mainmenu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" > 

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="75dp"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingTop="175dp" > 

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/onclicktextviewhighlight" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/onclicktextviewhighlight" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/optionsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/onclicktextviewhighlight" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show the xml, please? so we can find a fix.

Comment: You need to post the Layout xml, not the style or manifest. It would be on res/layout

Comment: Edited my opening post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have padding in your layout

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding. Like tyczj said. Also there IS a horizontal line

[image]